# rename column name in data frame by just one column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame(black) in R by just one column. I need to rename column by a new name(black_module).

I read this data frame from black.txt as a file by below code:

```
black = read.delim('black.txt, header =FALSE)
```

and then for rename of the column, I use below code:

```
colnames(black) <- c("black_module")
```

but when I colnames(black), I see V1 and I can't see black_module as a column name.

I don't know what is my problem. I appreciate if anybody guide me.

Comment: Please check the `str(black)` after reading the dataset.  It could give some insights about the data.  May be, it is not read correctly..  I see some misspelling `heder = FALSE` should be `header = FALSE`

Comment: @akrun I check by str(black) and get below result in console:                                         
                                                                                                      
 str(black)
'data.frame': 118 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 118 levels "ABCG8","ADAMTS16",..: 91 72 46 23 37 30 15 19 89 93 ...

Comment: Maybe `names(black) <- "black_module"`.

Comment: Missing a closing `'` in first line

Answer (score 0):

After you run `colnames(black)`, like you stated above, try `black$black_module <- black$V1; black$V1 <- NULL`